# IntelliJ not Recognizing Environment Variables for Artifactory in Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea

I'm experiencing an issue with IntelliJ IDEA where it's not recognizing my environment variables related to Artifactory in my `build.gradle` file. The variables are API keys that get refreshed frequently via the CLI, so they need to be dynamic.

In my `build.gradle`, I'm attempting to set these variables like so:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { 
        url System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_URL'] + '/artifactory/libs-release'
        credentials {
            username System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT']
            password System.getenv()['ARTIFACTORY_SVC_ACCT_PWD']
        } 
    }
}
```

I see that this issue has been similarily logged here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-265114/Gradle-is-not-picking-up-environment-variables-in-WSL2

This setup works perfectly fine when I build from the command line, but the environment variables are not being populated within IntelliJ IDEA.

I can see this by printing out one of my environment variables from my build.gradle. From my CLI I can see:

```
> Configure project :

Artifactory URL https://my.tcc.li

Artifactory URL https://my.tcc.li

Artifactory URL https://my.tcc.li
```

From Intellij's build tools I get null values:

```
> Configure project :

Artifactory URL null

Artifactory URL null

Artifactory URL null
```

### Workaround

Workaround:

I have found a temporary workaround for this issue. When I encounter this problem in IntelliJ, I perform the following steps:

- Run `gradlew --stop` in a separate terminal.
- Close IntelliJ.
- Reopen IntelliJ.

Does anybody understand why this works?

### Additional Context:

I've noticed that some of my teammates who have a similar setup to mine, which includes using `SDKman` for managing the Java environment, are experiencing this issue as well. However, those who are using a base Java environment without an environment manager seem to fare better.

**Current version of Intellij**:

```
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.1 (Ultimate Edition)
Build #IU-231.8770.65, built on April 27, 2023
Runtime version: 17.0.6+10-b829.9 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 12.6.3
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON
Kotlin: 231-1.8.21-IJ8770.65
```

Comment: How do you set the system environment in the WSL? It can simply print some persisted env like "PATH".